# Need help on how to create/save a template in demo.docusign.net using an API call in C#

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Hi I'm new at using Docusign, need help on how to create/save a template in https://demo.docusign.net/Member/ManageEnvelopes.aspx using an API call in C#.

I have used `POST https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountid}/templates`, but I get `The remote server returned an error:(400) Bad Request." Here is my C# code.

**Entity Get Set**

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Common.Info.DocuSign

{

[Serializable]
public class GetLoginAccountDataJsonResponse
{
    public List<LoginAccount> LoginAccounts { get; set; }
}     

[Serializable]
public class LoginAccount
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("accountId")]
    public string AccountId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("baseUrl")]
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isDefault")]
    public string IsDefault { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("siteDescription")]
    public string SiteDescription { get; set; }
    }               
}
```

**DocuSign.ascx.cs**

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.IO;

using System.Net;

using System.Web;

using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

using Common.Info.DocuSign;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

protected void lnkMytest_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    try

    {

        PostTemplate();

    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\nError: \n\n" + ex.Message);

    }
}

private void PostTemplate()

{

try

    {

        string documentName = "7455_Company.pdf";
        string url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
        string authenticateStr = @"
                         {
                            ""Username"": ""Enter_Username"",
                            ""Password"": ""Enter_Password"",
                            ""IntegratorKey"": ""Enter_IntegratorKey"",
                         }";

        //Start Get baseUrl
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        GetLoginAccountDataJsonResponse gladjr = jss.Deserialize<GetLoginAccountDataJsonResponse>(responseText);
        string baseUrl = gladjr.LoginAccounts[0].BaseUrl;
        sr.Close();
        //End Get baseUrl

        //Start Post Template
        url = baseUrl + "/templates";
       //url =https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/816391/templates


        string body = @"
            {
            ""emailSubject"": ""Company Plan 7455"",
            ""documents"": [
                            {
                                ""name"": ""7455_Company.pdf"",
                                ""documentId"": ""7455""
                            }
                           ],
            ""recipients"": {
                            ""signers"": [
                                            {
                                            ""email"": ""jazytest2014@gmail.com"",
                                            ""name"": ""jazy test2014"",
                                            ""recipientId"": 1,
                                            ""roleName"": ""Signer"",
                                            ""tabs"": {
                                                        ""signHereTabs"": [
                                                                            {
                                                                            ""anchorString"": ""Authorized Signature:"",
                                                                            ""anchorXOffset"": ""35"",
                                                                            ""anchorYOffset"": -3,
                                                                            ""anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent"": ""false"",
                                                                            ""anchorUnits"": ""mms"",
                                                                            ""xPosition"": ""420"",
                                                                            ""yPosition"": ""155"",
                                                                            ""documentId"": ""7455"",
                                                                            ""pageNumber"": 1
                                                                            }
                                                                          ]
                                                    }
                                             }
                                        ],
                            ""carbonCopies"": [
                                                {
                                                    ""email"": ""josytest2014@gmail.com"",
                                                    ""name"": ""josy aragon"",
                                                    ""emailNotification"": {
                                                                            ""emailSubject"": ""Company Plan 7455"",
                                                                            ""supportedLanguage"": ""en""
                                                                            },
                                                    ""recipientId"": 2,
                                                    ""roleName"": ""Signer's Copy""
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    ""email"": ""angsales2014@gmail.com"",
                                                    ""name"": ""Ang Sales"",
                                                    ""emailNotification"": {
                                                                            ""emailSubject"": ""Company Plan 7455"",
                                                                            ""supportedLanguage"": ""en""
                                                                            },
                                                    ""recipientId"": 3,
                                                    ""roleName"": ""Carbon Copy 3""
                                                }
                                               ]
                            },
            ""envelopeTemplateDefinition"": {
                                            ""name"": ""Company Plan 7455"",
                                            ""owner"": {
                                                        ""email"": ""josytest2014@gmail.com""
                                                        }
                                            },
            ""status"": ""sent""
            }";

        HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);                
        request2.Method = "POST";
        request2.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
        request2.Accept = "application/json";
        request2.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=myboundary";

        string requestBodyStart =
                "\r\n" +
                "\r\n" +
                "--myboundary\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" +
                "Content-Disposition: form-data" +
                "\r\n" +
                "\r\n" +
                body +
                "\r\n" +
                "\r\n" +
                "--myboundary\r\n" +
                "Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n" +
                "Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"" + documentName + "\"; documentid=1 \r\n" +
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n" +
                "\r\n";
        string requestBodyEnd = "--myboundary--\r\n" + "\r\n";

        string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/pdftest/");
        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath + documentName);

        byte[] bodyStart = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBodyStart.ToString());
        byte[] bodyEnd = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBodyEnd.ToString());
        Stream dataStream = request2.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(bodyStart, 0, requestBodyStart.ToString().Length);

        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        int len;
        while ((len = fileStream.Read(buf, 0, 4096)) > 0)
        {
            dataStream.Write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        dataStream.Write(bodyEnd, 0, requestBodyEnd.ToString().Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(requestBodyStart + requestBodyEnd);

        //I get error after request2.GetResponse() "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."                        
        HttpWebResponse webResponse2 = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();                
        StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(webResponse2.GetResponseStream());
        string responseText2 = sr2.ReadToEnd();

        //End Post Template
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\nAPI Call Result: \n\n" + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP 400 usually means the data you posted is malformed.  check your JSON and verify it matches up to what the server expects.

Answer (score 2):

`email_subject` needs to be changed to `emailSubject`.

Other than that, your code with my PDF Bytes gets me a successful template creation.

## Request:

```
--myboundary
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
    "emailSubject": "Company Plan 7455",
    "documents": [
        {
            "name": "7455_Company.pdf",
            "documentId": "7455"
        }
    ],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "jazytest2014@gmail.com",
                "name": "jazy test2014",
                "recipientId": 1,
                "roleName": "Signer",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "anchorString": "Authorized Signature:",
                            "anchorXOffset": "35",
                            "anchorYOffset": -3,
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                            "anchorUnits": "mms",
                            "xPosition": "420",
                            "yPosition": "155",
                            "documentId": "7455",
                            "pageNumber": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "carbonCopies": [
            {
                "email": "josytest2014@gmail.com",
                "name": "josy aragon",
                "emailNotification": {
                    "emailSubject": "Company Plan 7455",
                    "supportedLanguage": "en"
                },
                "recipientId": 2,
                "roleName": "Signer's Copy"
            },
            {
                "email": "angsales2014@gmail.com",
                "name": "Ang Sales",
                "emailNotification": {
                    "emailSubject": "Company Plan 7455",
                    "supportedLanguage": "en"
                },
                "recipientId": 3,
                "roleName": "Carbon Copy 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    "envelopeTemplateDefinition": {
        "name": "Company Plan 7455",
        "owner": {
            "email": "josytest2014@gmail.com"
        }
    },
    "status": "sent"
}
--myboundary
Content-Type:application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="7455_Company.pdf"; documentid=7455
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

<Base64 PDFBytes Omitted>
--myboundary--
```

## Response:

```
201
{
"templateId": "{templateId}",
"name": "Company Plan 7455",
"uri": "/templates/{templateId}"
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir I have change email_subject to emailSubject but I'm getting an error "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Comment: Hi Sir I have change email_subject to emailSubject but I'm getting an error "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." did i miss something in my C# code? 
Here is my code 
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082881/need-help-on-how-to-save-a-template-in-https-demo-docusign-net-member-manageen"

Comment: Can you update your question with the current traffic being passed? Also can you post the JSON response? there should be an error being passed with the 400. I'd suggest using Fiddler2 or something similar to capture the network traffic for the request/response